# Moose: type libraries (MooseX::Types)

Tags: perl, moose

I am trying to figure out the proper way to incorporate Moose in my project. [Here](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/MooseX-Types-0.46/lib/MooseX/Types.pm) I found an article suggesting that Moose types should be organized in type libraries, which seems like a good idea. So I wrote the following code basing on the provided example:

file 1: MyTypeLib.pm

```
package MyTypeLib;
use MooseX::Types -declare => [ qw( MyStatus ) ];
use MooseX::Types::Moose qw/Int/;

subtype MyStatus,
      as Int,
      where { $_ >= 0 && $_ < 10 },
      message { "Wrong status: $_" };

1;
```

file 2: MyTest.pm

```
package MyTest;
use MyTypeLib qw( MyStatus );
use Moose;

has status => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'MyStatus' );

no Moose; 1;
```

file 3: MyMain.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyTest;

my $t1 = MyTest->new('status' => 5);
```

When I run it I get this message:

> Attribute (status) does not pass the type constraint because:
>   Validation failed for 'MyStatus' with value 5 (not isa MyStatus) at
>   C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\Moose\Object.pm line 24

When I keep subtype definition in MyTest.pm and don't use MooseX::Types, everything works as expected. But the point is to move subtypes to a separate package and use them in other packages.
Could someone please advise how to make it work, or point to (or post) some working example, or suggest the alternative way of achieving the goal.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes: `isa => MyStatus`, not `isa => 'MyStatus'`. `MyStatus` is a constant-like function *exported* from your type library. Providing a string rather than a proper type constraint for `isa` ("stringy types") causes it to be looked up in Moose's type registry, or, if it's not found there, it's interpreted as the name of a class, and the type is inferred to be "any object of that class or its subclasses". Stringy types are less explicit and less flexible than using actual types, and more prone to conflicts since they all share a global namespace. It's best not to use them and type lbraries at the same time.

Comment: Is there any good source of examples on this topic? That example from CPAN simply does not work for types like subtype ArrayRefOfPositiveInt, as ArrayRef[PositiveInt]; How to define something like this without making it a 'stringy type'?

Comment: @AndyH it works just fine. Make sure you've actually imported `ArrayRef` and defined `PositiveInt`, and if it still doesn't work then ask another, specific, question.

Comment: You are right, I did not import ArrayRef. I just copied/pasted that example :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

MyTypeLib.pm

```
package MyTypeLib;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;

subtype MyStatus =>
      as 'Num' =>
      where { $_ >= 0 && $_ < 10 },
      message { "Wrong status: $_" };

#coerce MyStatus => from Int => via { $_ };
1;
```

MyTest.pm

```
package MyTest;
use MyTypeLib;
use Moose;

has status => ( is  => 'rw', 
                isa => 'MyStatus', 
                #coerce => 1 i
);

no Moose; 1;
```

MyMain.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyTest;
use Data::Dumper;

my $t1 = MyTest->new( status => 5);
print Dumper $t1;
my $t2 = MyTest->new( status => 10);
```

Which gives

```
$ perl MyMain.pl
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'status' => 5
               }, 'MyTest' );
Attribute (status) does not pass the type constraint because: Wrong
status: 10 at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-
2level/Moose/Exception.pm line 37
```

There isn't much information on this aspect of Moose but it looks like `Moose::Util::TypeConstraints` is the MooseX module folded into Moose.

---

EDIT
Removed coerce!

> You also need an explicit coercion.-

Comment: This also works but requires extra step (coercion) comparing to solution by hobbs. Anyway, it's good to know alternatives. Thank you!

Comment: @AndyH actually the coercion here is unnecessary and doesn't do anything. But it's still the "wrong" answer because it throws away what you did with a type library in favor of stringy types.

Comment: @hobbs You're right, no need for the coerce, I've taken it out. However this version doesn't allow for `MyStatus` to remain unquoted. The "wrong" answer but I'll leave it here for reference!